# Export VM from Hyper-v as OVF

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, virtual-machines, hyper-v, vhd, ovf

Using Windows Server 2008 R2 and Hyper-V.

I'm migrating all our VMs from Hyper-V to VMWare, and in order to facilitate this I've been asked by our IT support to provide them with the VM in `.ovf` format.

So far I've shutdown and exported the VM from within Hyper-V, this successfully produces a `.vhd` file.

What do I need to do in order to provide a `.ovf` format?

I've downloaded [StarWind V2V Converter](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/converter) which allows the converting of image files, but none of the output formats include `.ovf`. See image;

[image]

I've also tried [VMware vCenter Converter Standalone](https://my.vmware.com/en/group/vmware/evalcenter?p=converter) but it doesn't offer me the option to upload my local `.vhd` file - see image.

[image]

It looks like the converter can only connect to a Hyper-V server, whereas I have Hyper-V installed on a Windows 200 R2 server :/

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

`.ovf` contains not only the virtual machine disks but also its metadata and configuration. That means there is no way to convert a `.vhdx` file (which is just a disk) into `.ovf`.

In order to migrate to VMware from Hyper-V you have to use [StarWind V2V Converter](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/converter) recoding your .`vhdx` files to `.vmdk` including **hardware patching** and probably **enabling rescue mode** (these are V2V converter features that are crucial for such kind of migrations) to ensure target virtual machine successfully boots after conversion. The only thing left is to create a similar virtual machine on VMware and use the existing (previously converted) disk.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My files are `vhd` not `vhdx` - does this make a difference, and I don't see any option for hardware patching or enabling rescue mode in StarWind V2V Converter.

Comment: You can do the same procedure converting vhd either vhdx to vmdk

Answer (score -2):

Try to use Vmware standalone converter. This should do the trick:

https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/info?slug=infrastructure_operations_management/vmware_vcenter_converter_standalone/5_5

Comment: Why not tell the converter to connect directly to the Hyper-V, from there it will fetch and convert the VMs (Even if they are offline) it has not difference.

Comment: in my case, I have CLI-only linux VMs, and they are vertical market machines, meaning I am not able to install software like the converter on to the VM.